# tableView misplaced when running iOS 9 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, tableview

I am trying to lower the deployment target of my app from iOS 11 to iOS 9 but for some reason, some of my layout is misplaced, the most significant one is a tableview.

**How it looks on iOS 11.0:**

[image: First picture]

**How it looks on iOS lower than 11.0 (Notice the space between the `navigationBar` and the `tableView`)
[image: Second picture]**

The constraints I use are:

- Align trailing to Safe Area
- Align Leading to Safe Area
- Align Bottom to Safe Area
- Align Top to Safe Area

I have tried implementing `layoutIfNeeded()` but to no success, any ideas why this happens?

Comment: try self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
or select viewcontroller from stoaryborad and go to attribute inspecter then disable Adjusts ScrollView Insets

Comment: @karthikeyan that did the trick!

Comment: is everything okay now? shall i make it an answer?

Comment: @karthikeyan Yes my man, post it and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin)

You need to disable following property.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

or

**select viewcontroller from stoaryborad and go to attribute inspecter then disable Adjusts ScrollView Insets**

[image]